# How to change ID using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I change ID using Kotlin, so when I use SetOnClickListener it changes the ID of something?

Comment: why you want do that?

Comment: yourView.id = yourNewId

Answer (score 1):

Changing ID's isn't really possible as the R file is generated and not supposed to be modified, especially while the App is running.

I'm sure there is another solution for what you want to do, if you just want to reference another view depending on if or how often setOnClickListener was called you can just use a id variable in your class and/or a when statement to reference specific views conditionally

Answer (score 1):

As Merthan E and Marcin Orlowski already mentioned:
Don't even try to do it, even if it would be possible, it seems like you have to rethink your concept of using your views and their ids.

If you REALLY, REALLY have to store another identifier or a value in your view, you could use a tag (see the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#tags)).

But I would recommend to rather work with Lists, Arrays, something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. ID are constants and cannot be changed. If you think you need to do that, then I would rather say there's something fundamentally broken in your app design.